# Why OverflowError occured only on PySide6?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

When creating a Time series graph in QChartView, it occurs in the process of setting axis_x.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import collections

# PySide6
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import QPointF, QDateTime, QPoint
from PySide6.QtCharts import (QChartView, QLineSeries, QValueAxis,
                              QChart, QDateTimeAxis)

# PyQt5
# from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow
# from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, QDateTime, QPoint
# from PyQt5.QtChart import QChartView, QLineSeries, QValueAxis, QChart, QDateTimeAxis


class VisibilityView(QChartView):

    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget, maxlen: int):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.setMaximumSize(600, 400)

        self.maxlen = maxlen

        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.legend().setVisible(False)

        self.setChart(chart)
        self.chart().setTheme(QChart.ChartThemeDark)
        self.series = QLineSeries(name='Prevailing Visibility')
        chart.addSeries(self.series)

        axis_x = QDateTimeAxis()
        axis_x.setFormat('yy/MM/dd hh:mm')
        axis_x.setTitleText('Time')

        epoch = [1655168220000, 1655168230000, 1655168881000, 1655169840000,
                 1655169900000, 1655169960000, 1655170020000, 1655170080000,
                 1655170140000, 1655170200000, 1655170260000, 1655170320000,
                 1655170380000, 1655170500000, 1655170560000]
        vis_list = [20.0, 17.0, 20.0, 20.0,
                    19.0, 20.0, 15.0, 20.0,
                    20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0,
                    17.0, 20.0, 20.0]

        data = []

        for i in range(len(epoch)):
            data.append((epoch[i], vis_list[i]))
        self.data = collections.deque(data, maxlen=1440)

        left = QDateTime.fromMSecsSinceEpoch(self.data[0][0])
        right = QDateTime.fromMSecsSinceEpoch(self.data[-1][0])
        axis_x.setRange(left, right)
        chart.setAxisX(axis_x, self.series)

        axis_y = QValueAxis()
        axis_y.setRange(0, 20)
        axis_y.setLabelFormat('%d km')
        axis_y.setTitleText('Distance (km)')
        chart.setAxisY(axis_y, self.series)

        data_point = [QPointF(t, v) for t, v in self.data]
        self.series.append(data_point)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    graph = VisibilityView(window, 1440)
    window.setCentralWidget(graph)
    window.resize(graph.maximumSize())
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Result:

```bash
...
  File "D:\Workspace\convert_pyside\src\visibility_view.py", line 94, in __init__
    data_point = [QPointF(t, v) for t, v in self.data]
  File "D:\Workspace\convert_pyside\src\visibility_view.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
    data_point = [QPointF(t, v) for t, v in self.data]
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

However, if you proceed with PyQt5 with the same code, the error does not occur.

sys.maxsize is 9223372036854775807, which is the same for both environments.
Is there an internal difference PySide and PyQt?
And how do i proceed to solve this problem on PySide?

Comment: Without a [mre] it's difficult to help you. Nonetheless, what if you do `data_point = [QPointF(float(t), float(v)) for t, v in self.data]`? Btw, yes, there *are* differences between PySide and PyQt: while they practically do almost the same things, they are *not* the same (and that's also the reason for which they can **not** be used together).

Comment: Sorry, I modified it to make it workable. Thank you.

Comment: Please answer my question: try to convert the int values to float *before* using them for the QPointF constructor.

Comment: @musicamante omg.. you're right. As you said, I set it in the form of **float** instead of int, so I don't find any errors.
I changed it from `epoch = [1655168220000, ...]` to `epoch = [1655168220000.0, ...]`.
Thank you. You’re awesome!

Comment: Glad it worked. Keep in mind that: 1. Python is a *dynamic typing* language; 2. PyQt/PySide are *bindings* for the Qt library, which is written in C++ and uses *static* typing. While the *cleverness* of the Python language allows us to generally ignore those aspects, working with other languages can be an issue. In computing, there are *many* ways of representing numbers, including "simple" numbers (i.e. variables that will always represent *positive* integer values have different *types* than those that can also represent *negative* values). With *strict* python libraries this is almost ->

Comment: -> always transparent to developers, but when dealing with bindings that use static typings this can be an issue. Normally, Qt is quite "permissive", especially thanks to the Python bindings that do "under-the-hood" conversions, but that doesn't always happen. In fact, in more recent versions, the bindings show a conversion warning explaining that, while the arguments are accepted, they might be invalid in future versions. Simply put, whenever you get some unexpected behavior, **always** look for the original C++ function signature documentation and eventually consider proper value conversion.